# JFrame Repaint() Individual Component

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Is it possible to repaint only a specific component in a JFrame, rather than the entire thing? If this is possible, how would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can suggest the repainting of a single component by calling `repaint();` on that component only. Per the [Component API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint--):

> ```
> public void repaint()
> ```
>
> Repaints this component.
>
> If this component is a lightweight component, this method causes a call to this component's paint method as soon as possible. Otherwise, this method causes a call to this component's update method as soon as possible.